# He carried or delivered me to Peshawar in a BMW?

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following sentences is more suitable?

> 1. He delivered me to Peshawar in a BMW.
> 2. He carried me to Peshawar in a BMW.

Should I use *delivered* or *carried*?

Answer (score 12):

It might be **delivered**, but that sounds like you were a package.
The car **carried** you not the driver.

A better alternative would be

> He **drove** me to Peshawar in a BMW.

Answer (score 7):

You **deliver** things- a parcel, some goods, a meal. You do not deliver people.

When you **carry** comething, you move it bodily- in your arms or on your back.

You could consider eiher **drive** or **take**. both would imply that he is driving the car.

Comment: I spent some time trying to think of some good counterexamples – like: _I delivered our daughter back to campus after spring break and we carried her suitcase in the back seat_ – but they all sounded so awkward I gave up and decided to upvote. Unless the O.P. is a pizza, _drove_ and _took_ are indeed much better choices than _delivered_ or _carried_.

Comment: I **have** heard somebody say that they had delivered their daughter to college, but the choice of words was intentionally facetious.

Answer (score 6):

"He drove me..." is neutral.

"He delivered me..." implies that your presence at Peshawar had been demanded.   "The boss sent for me.  I was delivered to Peshawar in a BMW."  Or there's a (possibly humorous) implication that the passenger(s) were considered as goods.  "We called the girls' school for some dancing partners.  Several were delivered in a BMW."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is about taking someone to some place in a car, so *delivered* is more appropriate.

---

Here is a related definition of *deliver* given by Macmillan:

> **[deliver](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/deliver#deliver__1)**
>   1b. to take someone to a place where they will be guarded or taken care of
>   **deliver someone to:** *He was safely delivered to his hotel*.

The other choice, *carry*, can be used for taking someone (or something) somewhere, too, but if the trip happens in a vehicle, it's used when the vehicle does the action (i.e., the vehicle is the subject of the sentence), not the driver. For example,

> **[carry](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/carry_1#carry_1__1)**
>   1d. if a vehicle carries someone or something somewhere, it takes them there
>   *An airplane carrying 120 passengers has crashed in India.*

Comment: Interesting answer, with some good references. That said, I think the "where they will be guarded or taken care of" part of the definition of _deliver_ is vital. If the O.P. is a wanted criminal and there is a safe house in Peshawar, then _delivered_ would be fine. If it's just a ride home from our golf outing, though, I don't think _delivered_ is the best word to use. Similarly, _carry_ works well when citing impersonal facts ("My minivan can carry seven passengers," e.g.), but it seems a bit too impersonal if I'm talking about giving you a lift somewhere.

Comment: @J.R. Me either. I thought to myself before posting this answer, "In what dialect or register would people use 'delivered' this way?" -- I wrote my answer because I thought nobody would answer the question (but I finished typing my answer third). My natural choice would be *drive*, too. Then again, I believe that this question was taken from a test or an exercise in a book, that's why I focused only on the two verbs. Personally, I agree with all your points.

Comment: @J.R "delivered" would be appropriate (but slightly facetious) if after the golf outing, your activities at the 19th hole had left you somewhat inebriated. (Note "taken care of" in the dictionary definition).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best phrase is "He brought me to Peshawar." That leaves any question of vehicle type or reason for going completely out of the phrasing.

Comment: Unless you _want_ to emphasize the mode of transportation, or vehicle type (which I assume the O.P. wants to do in this case, given the BMW reference).

Answer (score 0):

"Brought" is still the best choice for modern English usage. "Delivered" and "carried" both have a strong connotation of a non-human object; "brought" can be used with human and non-human objects.

Answer (score -1):

According to the current text of the question, it is impossible to answer as there is not enough context. By what means of transport did you get to Peshawar?

'Carried' implies 'carrying by hand', which is normally unlikely. 'Delivered' is normally used for a package, but might be suitable here. 'He drove me to Peshawar in a BMW' is probably what you want.